# What is the difference between catastrophic failures and interrupting?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

From the [Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2](https://www.apress.com/br/book/9781484231494) book (page 417):

> **The ASP.NET Debugging Levels**
>    ...
>   **Critical** - This level is used for messages that describe *catastrophic failures*.
>   **Error** - This level is used for messages that describe errors that *interrupt* the application....

What is the difference between *catastrophic failures* and *interrupting*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Microsoft documentation explains it a little more clearly when discussing log levels:

- Error = 4

> For errors and exceptions that cannot be handled. These messages indicate a failure in the current activity or operation (such as the
>   current HTTP request), not an application-wide failure. Example log
>   message: Cannot insert record due to duplicate key violation.

- Critical = 5

> For failures that require immediate attention. Examples: data loss
>   scenarios, out of disk space.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x (under the "Log Level" section.

In other words, level 4 "error" will be used for something which crashes the application in its current activity, but probably don't prevent it from continuing to serve other requests or perform other operations. Most exceptions will fall into this category.

On the other hand a level 5 "critical" error will be used for something which is likely to have a longer-term impact, potentially making the application entirely un-usable until the problem is resolved.